# Sharing images of ubuntu logo

Tags: logo, legal

This question does not directly pertain to the ubuntu operating system yet the promotion of it.I am a software developer and huge fan of ubuntu, linux, and open source software.

I am also a fan of giving credit where credit is due and avoiding copyright infringement (though as far as I know I doubt Canonical wouldn’t be likely to press charges for such under most circumstances).

Am I legally allowed to share images the ubuntu logo or name or similar media on my social media pages without infringing upon Canonical?

Answer (score 1):

Took this from the [ubuntu iP rights page](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy)

You can use the Trademarks, in accordance with Canonical’s brand guidelines, with Canonical’s permission in writing. If you require a Trademark licence, please contact us (as set out below).

You will require Canonical’s permission to use: (i) any mark ending with the letters UBUNTU or BUNTU which is sufficiently similar to the Trademarks or any other confusingly similar mark, and (ii) any Trademark in a domain name or URL or for merchandising purposes.

You cannot use the Trademarks in software titles. If you are producing software for use with or on Ubuntu you may reference Ubuntu, but must avoid: (i) any implication of endorsement, or (ii) any attempt to unfairly or confusingly capitalise on the goodwill of Canonical or Ubuntu.

You can use the Trademarks in discussion, commentary, criticism or parody, provided that you do not imply endorsement by Canonical.

You can write articles, create websites, blogs or talk about Ubuntu, provided that it is clear that you are in no way speaking for or on behalf of Canonical and that you do not imply endorsement by Canonical.

I highly recommend you read the actual site as this is just a spinet of the information on the site.

[Also here is the rights for the Ubuntu logo.](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo)

[Here is the rights for the canonical logo.](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/canonical-logo)